# where to put common logic in Flask routes

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application with many route endpoints. In each of those routes, I need to do some common operations like Authentication check, validation logic for permission, XSS validation and few more common validation logic. I have read few posts which says of using login_required decorator in every methods for the Authentication verification.

Now my question is should I create a decorator for each of the validation type and use them in every method. Please let me know how to handle such cases in Flask application.

```
@Login_required()
@Xss_validate()
@permission_check()
def subsribe_service(cs_dict, data_dict):
    Logic to subscribe....

@Login_required()
@Xss_validate()
@permission_check()
def unsubsribe_service(cs_dict, data_dict):
    Logic to unsubscribe....

@Login_required()
@Xss_validate()
@permission_check()
def delete_service(cs_dict, data_dict):
    Logic to delete....

@Login_required()
@Xss_validate()
@permission_check()
def edit_service(cs_dict, data_dict):
    Logic to edit....
```

As you can see I have common logic as a decorator in all the action methods. I have such decorators in all the applications since every action require those 3 logic.

Comment: You need to use [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/)

Comment: I don't understand how blueprint is going to solve the problem. Blueprints are meant to separate the applications.

Answer (score 1):

add: you can Pluggable Views similar to class based views:
egg:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)

class BaseViews(MethodView):
    decorators = [Login_required, Xss_validate, permission_check]

class SubsribeService(BaseViews):
    def get(self):
        # get Logic

    def post(self):
        # post logic

class EditService(BaseViews):
    def get(self):
        # get Logic

    def post(self):
        # post logic

app.add_url_rule('/subsribe_service/', view_func=SubsribeService.as_view('subsribe_service'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.add_url_rule('/edit_service/', view_func=EditService.as_view('edit_service'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

simple easy and beautiful..!

Answer (score 0):

take a look off this flask extensions
[Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Flask-Principal](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/)

those extensions already have everything you have mentioned

Comment: I think it is not about which extensions I use. It's about where do I keep those implementations.

Answer (score 0):

if your validation operations are done on all the views of a Blueprint or app then use `Flask.before_request or Blueprint.before_request` to decorate a function that will define the access rulers to the application or sub-application